# How to check if a long long can fit into a double variable

Tags: c, type-conversion, floating-accuracy

I'd like to check if a long long variable can be safely cast into a double. `DBL_MAX` doesn't help, because there are integers smaller than that which are not representable by double, while some of integers larger than `2^53` can still fit.

Is there a reliable way to do this?
Can a compiler optimise out a statement like the one below?

`(long long)((double)a) == a` (where `a` is a `long long`)

This does not ask for a *largest* integer that can be represented as double, I ask for a general function that can check if I can exactly convert *any* `long long` value to double without errors.

Comment: Could you please define what "safely cast into a double" means?

Comment: Test whether the last bits of `a` are zero if `a` is larger than pow(2, 53)? `clz(abs(a)) + ctz(abs(a)) > 64 - 53`?

Comment: I think the author is asking: "How can I ensure that there is no rounding error when I store a `long long` integer into a `double`, given there are integer values that a double cannot store?"

Comment: With the most common IEEE754 floating point implementations, this is not possible.

Comment: @user3470630 That's what I was thinking, until I saw the last line. `(long long) (3.12) == 3` should be evaluated as true.

Comment: @jdarthenay In the last line I assumed that a is `long long`

Comment: Not the point. I mean if `(double) 3` is `3.12` your last test would say `3.12` is a safe cast for `3` as a double...

Comment: I think your expression is fine, except for a large integer where (double) a equals 2^63, and you need to check whether the conversion back to long long might be undefined behaviour.

Comment: Voted to re-open as this post and voted duplicate, although both about `long long` and `double` are asking fundamental different questions.

Answer (score 1):

OP's method is a good start.

```
(long long)((double)a) == a
```

Yet has a problem.   E.g. `long long a = LLONG_MAX; ((double)a)` results is a rounded value exceeding `LLONG_MAX`.

The following will certainly not overflow `double`.
(Pathological exception: `LLONG_MIN` exceeds `-DBL_MAX`).

```
volatile double b = (double) a;
```

Converting back to `long long` and testing against `a` is sufficient to meet OP's goal.  Only need to insure `b` is in `long long` range.  [@gnasher729](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36699009/how-to-check-if-a-long-long-can-fit-into-a-double-variable#comment60986508_36699009) Let us assume 2's complement and `double` uses `FLT_RADIX != 10`.  In that case, the lowest `long long` is a power-of-2 and the highest is a power-of-2 minus 1 and conversion to `double` can be made exact with careful calculation of the `long long` limits, as follows.

```
bool check_ll(long long a) {
  constant double d_longLong_min = LLONG_MIN;
  constant double d_longLong_max_plus_1 = (LLONG_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0;
  volatile double b = (double) a;
  if (b < d_longLong_min || b >= d_longLong_max_plus_1) {
    return false;
  }
  return (long long) b == a;
}
```

[edit simplify - more general]

A test of `b` near `LLONG_MIN` is only needed when `long long` does not use 2's complement

```
bool check_ll2(long long a) {
  volatile double b = (double) a;
  constant double d_longLong_max_plus_1 = (LLONG_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0;
  #if LLONG_MIN == -LLONG_MAX
    constant double d_longLong_min_minus_1 = (LLONG_MIN/2 - 1)*2.0;;
    if (b <= d_longLong_min_minus_1 || b >= d_longLong_max_plus_1) {
      return false;
    }
  #else
    if (b >= d_longLong_max_plus_1) {
      return false;
    }
  #endif
  return (long long) b == a;
}
```

---

I would not expect a compile to be able to optimize out `(long long)((double)a) == a`.  IAC, by using an intermediate `volatile double`, code prevents that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can check this conversion before you cast, but `fenv.h` seems like it can help you for after-cast checking. `FE_INEXACT` can allow you to check if the operation you just performed could not be exactly stored.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfenv/FE_INEXACT/